# Implement event handler in a grid and concatenate values

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I'm looking for the way how to implement RowUpdated event handler in Answers grid. I've implemented RowUpdated event handler in the value column of the grid but it doesn't work.

[image]

I want to concatenate the value of the attribute column value in the description field when I change the value from the drop-down list

[image]

Can anyone provide advice please?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected virtual void CSAnswers_Value_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Works fine on my instance, **BUT** event will be raised only if

1. Focus has been changed
2. Ctrl+Enter pressed

Which is fine from my standpoint. Do you really need to get an event right after the value changing?

Comment: Hi Evgeny, yes I do, because I need to structure the description field in real time.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible inside the grid(